# PHPWord: fill a template and output .pdf

Tags: php, pdf, phpword

I'm using a PHPWord to create word documents. To do so I'm using layouts:

```
    $template = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor($this->config->application->fileTemplateFolder.'invoice.docx');
    $template->setValue('date', date("F jS, Y"));
    $temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'invoice_');
    $temp_file .= '.docx';
    $template->saveAs($temp_file);
```

It works fine. My problem is to create the a PDF file. Here is how I trying to create the file:

```
            $path = '/Users/andredx/Projects/x/vendor/dompdf/dompdf';

            require_once __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/dompdf/dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
            \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererPath($path);
            \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererName('DomPDF');

            $temp_doc = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($temp_file); // this line executes
            $xmlWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($temp_doc , 'PDF'); // this one get' my an error which I cannot see
            $xmlWriter->save('/Users/andredx/Projects/x/_test.pdf', TRUE);


            unlink($temp_file);
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Maybe the path of the converter, but I'm trying to insert the path in many ways and it is not working.

Relevant info: the document has images and tables.

Can you help me to find out what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: I had trouble with loading temp.docx because of the images, and solve it by direct output to PDF, without saving docx